# Python "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute" Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a Python code to extract the coordinates from the "inkscape" gcode file and use these coordinates as input at another function. Bay the way I am very beginner at programming and also Python. I wrote a very simple few lines, u can see below. When I try to run the code I am getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start' " error. I think it is about at the begging of the loop "xindex.start()" returns with null, so guess I need to define an initial value, but I couldn't find how to do it. The example code is only for the X value.

```
import re
  with open("example.gcode", "r") as file:
       for line in file:
        if line.startswith('G00') or line.startswith('G01'): # find the lines which start with G00 and G01
         xindex = re.search("[X]", line) # search for X term in the lines
         xindex_number = int(xindex.start()) # find starting index number and convert it to int
```

The inside of the gcode looks like :

```
S1; endstops
G00 E0; no extrusion
G01 S1; endstops
G01 E0; no extrusion
G21; millimeters
G90; absolute
G28 X; home
G28 Y; home
G28 Z; home
G00 F300.0 Z20.000; pen park !!Zpark
G00 F2400.0 Y0.000; !!Ybottom
....
```

Any help is appreciated

Wish u all have a nice day

Comment: Some of those lines don’t contain an “X”, so `re.search` returns `None`.

Comment: Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Comment: Maybe you can add a condition to check whether there was a match or not. And then run the method `xindex.start()`. The error is because in some lines the `re.search()` function doesn't find a match for `"[X]"` so it returns `None`. So add an `if` condition and it should work fine

Answer (score 3):

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'` means that you are trying to call `.start()` on an object that is equal to None.

You code is looking for the first line that starts with 'G00' or 'G01' which in this case would be the line: **"G00 E0; no extrusion"** and then it is trying to find where the letter X exists in that line.

In this case, 'X' does not exist in that line, hence `xindex = None`. Therefore, you cannot call `xindex.start()` without throwing an error. This is what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `if` condition and it should work fine

```py
import re
with open("example.gcode", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("G00") or line.startswith("G01"):
            xindex = re.search("[X]", line)

            # Check if a match was found
            if xindex:
                xindex_number = int(xindex.start())
```

And refer to [@QuantumMecha 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69625701/12033855) to understand why.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, I guessed the reason but I could not figure out how to solve it. As I said I am a very beginner at coding. Tried to define the initial value for the start function by making equal it to 0.0, but it didn't work. Now I get your and @QuantumMecha's point. Thank you for all.